# What can I do with a SQL Server diagram

Tags: sql-server, database, diagram

I created a SQL Server diagram in SSMS. This feature looks really great, but what can I do with it? :)

It's nice to have some kind of documentation, and it's nice that you can change a field within the diagram and this will have an effect on the actual table. But what are other reasons to create a diagram?

Is it possible for example to import a full diagram in any reporting tool? I noticed that the diagram is stored in a table which has a binary column in it with a long string. Can I copy/paste this in any other diagram tools?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have never succeeded in importing into other tools. I tried pasting it into Visio (2007) but I could not edit the object in Visio, Notice you can control how the pages are printed (Right click on the surface area and select show page breaks - you can drag the page breaks)  so that each printed page contains one or more complete tables. You can use the diagram to creating indexes and foreign key relationships.  I have printed out the main tables and taped it to my desk while working on a project.